# Prevent bootstrap reboot from styling hyperlinks

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to style my hyperlinks but Bootstrap 4 "Reboot" overwrites my css and changes the styling of my  links to this:

```
a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}
```

Other than copying the reboot css, modifying and hosting it locally, is there any way to prevent reboot from styling the links?  It does not matter if you load your custom css last, reboot always writes over the top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try !important at the and of the style.

```
a {
        color: #007bff !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works.  If you add !important then reboot does not overwrite it.

Comment: But using `!important` should be avoided in CSS, any other workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Adding `!important` at the end of style is the easy way but, that triggers a waterfall where you will need to add more `!important` in your styling files.
This is why you should learn tree structure of styling.
What I recommend is add a class name to your body tag and override *reboot.css* or whatever like

```
<body class="body-class-name">
```

and then go into your css file which has the highest priority and put

```
body.body-class-name .a{text-decoration: none}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Way better workaround then accepted answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks, that you load your CSS in the wrong sequence.

Put the bootstrap CSS above your own CSS.

Then you can overwrite bootstrap-settings without `!important` (which should still be the very last option).

Comment: Good catch :) thanks